# Consulta de intervalo de Datas em determinado Horário

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Tenho uma consulta que pega todos os dados entre um intervalo de dias.

Porém, gostaria que ele pegasse estes dados apenas em um intervalo de horas (de 08:00 às 17 por exemplo).

Minha consulta atualmente está assim:

```
select TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(DT, 'yyyy/MM/dd 
               hh24:Mi:ss'),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 
               'AMERICA/SAO_PAULO', 'dd/mm/yyyy') as Data, 
    AREA, VALOR 
    from TABELA where AREA = 'MINHAAREA' and 
    CODE = 'MEUCODE' and 
    DT >= to_date('01/05/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and 
    DT <= to_date('01/06/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
    order by DT
```

Comment: Ué não é só fazer: DT >= to_date('01/05/2019 08:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and 
    DT <= to_date('01/06/2019 17:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ?

Comment: Não, pois aí ele pegaria todos os dados do intervalo de dias de '01/05/2019 08:00:00' a 01/06/2019 17:00:00. O que eu quero é que ele pegue os dados de cada dia nesse intervalo de horas.

Comment: Então coloque mais duas condições especificando o horário, independente da data entre 08:00 e 17:00.

Comment: Ou ainda um EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) BETWEEN 8 AND 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o to_char e extraia a hora

```
select TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(DT, 'yyyy/MM/dd 
               hh24:Mi:ss'),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 
               'AMERICA/SAO_PAULO', 'dd/mm/yyyy') as Data, 
    AREA, VALOR 
    from TABELA where AREA = 'MINHAAREA' and 
    CODE = 'MEUCODE' and 
    TO_CHAR(DT,'HH24MI') BETWEEN '0800' AND '1759'
    order by DT
```